# Hadoop 2.3.0 Issue : -ls: For input string: "false"

Tags: hadoop2

I'm getting errors running simple hadoop fs commands. I'm on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5, I've configured hadoop as a standalone cluster.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls
2015-09-26 06:59:20,531 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-ls: For input string: "false"
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]

    $ hadoop fs -ls /
2015-09-26 07:26:16,629 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-ls: For input string: "false"
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]

$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop
2015-09-26 07:01:05,356 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-mkdir: For input string: "false"
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -mkdir [-p] <path> ...
```

I'm running a standalone hadoop 2.3.0 on OS X 10.10.5.

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.3.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1567123
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-02-11T13:40Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum dfe46336fbc6a044bc124392ec06b85
This command was run using /Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
I tried to fix the warning (so far without success).  I suspect the warning is an unrelated issue:

WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

$ env | grep HADOOP
HADOOP_HOME=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0/lib/native
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/conf
HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0/lib
```

Here are my hadoop config files which are in /Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.3.0/etc/hadoop/conf:

```
$ cat hdfs-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

$ cat core-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

$ cat mapred_site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

$ cat yarn_site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

$ jps
99664 NameNode
4997 Jps
2202 ZeppelinServer
2283 RemoteInterpreterServer
2158 JupyterScala
99006 SecondaryNameNode
```

Same issue with hadoop 2.6.1 (downloaded as binary):

```
$ bin/hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b4d876d837b830405ccdb6af94742f99d49f9c04
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-09-16T21:07Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum ba9a9397365e3ec2f1b3691b52627f
This command was run using /Users/davidlaxer/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar
$ bin/hadoop fs -ls /
2015-09-26 07:44:55,977 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-ls: For input string: "false"
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the config file: hdfs-site.xml 
I had:
false.
I changed it to:
0

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```